# Android linear layout image view and edit text on the same horizontal line

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying the `ImageView` and the `EditText` to be on the same line.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_flag"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    <!--  Phone number Label -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/signin_phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Phone Number"
            android:inputType="phone" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's how it looks like.

[image]

How can I make the phone number view and the image on the same center line? Thanks.

Comment: Please see my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to the LinearLayout

Comment: not working. I have to adjust with the margin bottom on the image view

Comment: Seems to be working perfectly for me, can you post the xml code for the whole layout, maybe another component is affecting the behavior of your linear layout

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drawableLeft` attribute in your `EditText` instead of taking another `ImageView` like this.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <!--  Phone number Label -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/signin_phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:hint="Phone Number"
            android:inputType="phone" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Or you might consider using `RelativeLayout` and then setting the gravity `layout_centerVertical` as true like the following..

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_flag"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    <!--  Phone number Label -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_flag">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/signin_phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Phone Number"
            android:inputType="phone" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need 'LinearLayout' you can easily accomplish this using a 'RelativeLayout' as a container and then using `android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/title"` in the individual views.